# Modify sudoers to bypass password requirements but it's not taking effect

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo, sudoers

I need to run a script with sudo without entering my password. I'm editing /etc/sudoers (using sudo visudo) and on the last line, I'm adding:

```
MY-USER-NAME ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

I just want to make sure that it works before specifying a script to disable sudo access. However whatever sudo command I run still needs me to enter a password. What am I doing wrong here? Could it be that /etc/sudoers is being overwritten somewhere else I'm not aware about?

Comment: In all the examples I have seen `NOPASSWD:` had a blank before the `ALL` like `NOPASSWD: ALL`. Reboot to check.

Comment: that's a very good point. I'll try it to make sure. I did other changes (password expiration time) that took effect immediately. Is rebooting really necessary?

Comment: Not if it works without boot.

Comment: This is baaaaad. That space did the job. Thanks a bunch for your help. Can you make it a post with a little info the format of the line so that I can select it as the right answer? The formatting was one of the things I missed big time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The
[sudoers(5)](https://man.archlinux.org/man/sudoers.5.en)
man-page specifies:

> Multiple arguments may be specified, separated by white space.

What is missing is the little white space after the `NOPASSWD:`,
to separate it from the next argument:

```
MY-USER-NAME ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```