# 'sudo adduser <user> sudo' succeeds, but still getting '<user> not in sudoers file'

Tags: linux, bash, debian, sudo

I'm on Debian 10. As root I issued `sudo adduser <user> sudo`, which succeeded. Repeating the command tells me that user  already exists. However, when logged in as  and issuing e.g. `sudo bash`, I still get the " is not in sudoers file" message I got before. What can I do?

Edit: The problem was that `/etc/sudoers` was not writable even to root.

Comment: does `newgrp sudo sudo bash` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What can I do?

As root run the following command:

```
sudo usermod -aG sudo {Username}
```

You can also just modify the file directly:  */etc/sudoers* by adding the appropriate line to the file.

```
username ALL=(ALL: ALL) ALL
```

Source: [How to add a user to Sudoers in Debian 11](https://itslinuxfoss.com/how-to-add-a-user-to-sudoers-in-debian-11/#:%7E:text=%20How%20to%20add%20a%20user%20to%20Sudoers,like%20a%20daunting%20task%20but%20in...%20More%20)

Comment: Syntax on the file needs to be specific, otherwise, weird things can happen[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1674221/modify-sudoers-to-bypass-password-requirements-but-its-not-taking-effect?rq=1). The best approach is to repeat the last line that contains a user and modify it

Comment: The most important thing is to use `visudo` to edit the file, to avoid locking yourself (or others!) out. Despite the name it will use `$EDITOR`, not necessarily `vi`.

Comment: @DanielB - Used vi on RHEL to add myself to the wheel group in the past without a problem. Couldn’t remember the syntax for usermod when I did it, one has to also, disconnect an OpenSSH connection and likely open a new console session to actually witness the group change using either method in my experience.